# wordpress custom loop ascending descending posts by custom field

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, sort

I am developing wordpress site that is depend upon price so i add custom filed named 'price'

```
<?php 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo  $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', TRUE);
endwhile;
 ?>
```

it is basic loop to show out price of all post. requirement : can anybody modify above so its shows post according ascending or descending order like every price site

Answer (score 2):

If you would have created your own WP_Query, you could have done it this way:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'price'
);
$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

See the examples in the docs:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Since you are using the Mainloop, you need to act a bit differently:

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_by_price' );
function order_by_price( $query ){
    if( ! $query->is_main_query() ) //If its not the main query return
        return;

    $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' );
}
?>
```

This will act on each Mainloop. So be careful. Maybe you want this to be applied only for specific post types. In this case, you should check this first:

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_by_price' );
function order_by_price( $query ){
    if( ! $query->is_main_query() ) //If its not the main query return
        return;

    if( 'product' != $query->get( 'post_type' ) ) //Apply only for 'product' post types
        return;

    $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' );
}
?>
```

Check also the Docs for this Actionhook:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: very informative reply but for like me newbie it is complicated so it is possible i can modify this code                                                            <?php 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo  $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', TRUE);
endwhile;
 ?>

Comment: try and add my second code into your functions.php and see, if it is ordered.